# How to define a class based on other classes declaration

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, inheritance, interface

I am building an online shopping website. I have created a class called *Item*, to contain all the common attributes of everything that I sell.

```
// all common attribues
class Item {
    int price;
    string title;
    string description;
    string category;
}
```

Now, I have more classes with additional properties, and they all contain *Item*:

```
class Shirt {
    Item item;
    string size;
    string color;
}

class Book {
    Item item;
    string author;
    int noOfPages;
}
```

Next step is to implement the search functionality for my website. I want to use **Elasticsearch**. I need to create one (and only one) document that contains all the fields that need to be searched:

```
class ElasticSearchDocument
{
    // these are coming from Item
    int price;
    string title;
    string category;

    // there are coming from Shirt
    string size;
    string color;

    // these are coming from Book
    string author;
}
```

Notice that *ElasticSearchDocument* will contain every property that need to be searched. I need *ElasticSearchDocument* class to send data to Elasticsearch.

Is there any way that I can use my other classes to build *ElasticSearchDocument*? i.e. would it be possible to derive ElasticSearchDocument from other classes, so if I change them I don't need to repeat the change in 2 places?

Or is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't the classes derive `Item` instead of contain it? Like `class Book : Item { ... }`?

Comment: Thanks... no particular reason... I was not entirely sure which approach is better... I chose this approach, as I thought in it is not possible to inherit from multiple classes... In my actual design I have Item, Address, etc classes that are needed in the final class

Comment: It is the difference between "is a" and "has a". A skirt "has an" item? No. A skirt "is an" item so it should inherit Item. Suppose you had a Dog class and a Collar class. A dog "has a" collar so a property of type Collar should be part of the Dog class.

Comment: Thanks, nicely explained

Comment: I ended up implementing [this solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192352/defining-classes-using-a-combination-of-inheritance-and-composition)